# PowerShell - Get-GhildItem - Ignore specific directory

Tags: powershell

I am working with a script to clear old files off our file server. We are using this line in the script to find all files older than a certain date:

```
$oldFiles = Get-ChildItem $oldPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.lastwritetime -le $oldDate }
```

My question is, how do I ignore a certain directory in the $oldPath? For instance, if we had the following:

- root

  - dir1
  - dir 2

    - subdir 1
    - subdir 2
  - dir 3

    - subdir 1
  - dir 4

And we want to ignore `dir 2` and all subdirectories when building the list

Final working script:

```
$oldPath = "\\server\share"
$newDrive = "I:"
$oldDate = Get-Date -Date 1/1/2012

$oldFiles = Get-ChildItem $oldPath -Recurse -File | Where-Object {($_.PSParentPath -notmatch '\\Ignore Directory')  -and $_.lastwritetime -le $oldDate }
$oldDirs = Get-ChildItem $oldPath -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.PSParentPath -notmatch '\\Ignore Directory')} | select-object FullName
$oldDirs = $oldDirs | select -Unique

foreach ($oldDir in $oldDirs) {
    $strdir = $newDrive + "\" + ($oldDir | Split-Path -NoQualifier | Out-String).trim().trim("\")
    if (!(Test-Path $strdir)) {
        Write-Host "$strdir does not exist. Creating directory..."
        mkdir $strdir | Out-Null
    } # end if
} # end foreach

foreach ($file in $oldFiles) {
    $strfile = $newDrive + "\" + ($file.FullName | Split-Path -NoQualifier | Out-String).trim().trim("\")
    Write-Host "Moving $file.FullName to $strfile..."
    Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $strfile -Force -WhatIf
} # end foreach

$oldfiles | select pspath | Split-Path -NoQualifier | Out-File "\\nelson\network share\ArchivedFiles.txt"
```

Comment: Shouldn't the -notmatch argument be `\\dir 2` instead of `\\zzz` or is `zzz` really the name of the dir?

Comment: zzz was a directory I put in there for testing. The current code segment reflects two random directories I am having it ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your Where-Object condition to:

```
... | Where-Object {($_.PSParentPath -notmatch '\\dir 2') -and ($_.lastWriteTime -le $oldDate)}
```

Also, you probably want to filter out directory items as well so that $oldFiles contains only files e.g.:

```
$oldFiles = Get-ChildItem $oldPath -Recurse | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.PSParentPath -notmatch '\\dir 2') -and ($_.lastWriteTime -le $oldDate)}
```

If you're on PowerShell v3 you can use a new parameter on Get-ChildItem to simplify this to:

```
$oldFiles = Get-ChildItem $oldPath -Recurse -File | Where {($_.PSParentPath -notmatch '\\dir 2') -and ($_.lastWriteTime -le $oldDate)}
```

Comment: I seem to be having issues with this. I left out the `-file` since I need the directories to rebuild the directory structure on the target. Here is what I have:

`$oldFiles = Get-ChildItem $oldPath -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.PSParentPath -notmatch '\\zzz') -and $_.lastwritetime -le $oldDate }`

My move command looks like this:

`foreach ($file in $oldFiles) {
    $strfile = $newDrive + ($file | Split-Path -NoQualifier | Out-String).trim()
    Write-Host "Moving $file to $strfile..."
    Move-Item $file -Destination $strfile -Force -WhatIf
} # end foreach`

Comment: But I keep getting this error: `Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\myaccount\Desktop\file.ext'`. Any idea why it is losing the path?

Comment: If you are keeping the directories in the $oldFiles list then it is like that you've previously moved the file by moving one of its parent directories.

Comment: That may be what I'm doing. I posted the full script up in my original post. Do you see something wrong that would cause this?

Comment: You really should not have Directory only entries in $oldFiles because your loop will do a move-item on those directories and directory items will appear before the files in them.  If you are on Powershell v3 use -file on the Get-ChildItem otherwise use the !$_PSContainer test in the where block.  After that, let's debug what other problems crop up.

Comment: OK, I modified it to have the -file and used basically the same thing to pull out the directories into that variable. Still getting the errors. It is wanting to move the files from my desktop to the target. I will update my original post to reflect the current script.

Comment: Seems to be a few problems with my moving loop. For one, the $strfile doesn't seem to contain any path information whatsoever. The current output is: `Moving FILE.ext to I:\testFILE.ext...
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\FILE.ext' because it does not exist.` The I:\testFILE.ext should read I:\Directory\FILE.ext.

Comment: Where you originally assign $oldDirs, get rid of the Split-Path at the end of that pipe.  I think you may be splitting too many times.  Also becaues of the way you're computing $oldDirs now, you don't need the next line that does the Select -unique.

Comment: See above, the .FullName got me where I needed to be. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$exclude = Join-Path $oldPath 'dir 2'
$oldFiles = Get-ChildItem $oldPath -Recurse | ? {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
  $_.FullName -notlike "$exclude\*" -and
  $_.LastWriteTime -le $oldDate
}
```

Comment: I tried this and had the same problems as the other suggestion. I seem to be losing my directory structure in the $oldFiles and when I try to move the files it tries to find them in whatever directory the script is running from. `Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\myaccount\Desktop\file.ext` I will edit my post to include the full script.

Comment: `$oldFiles` contains a list of file objects. The default property of these objects is `Name` (i.e. the filename without the path), so using `$file` is the same as `$file.Name`. This will cause cmdlets to look for the file in the current working directory. Use `$file.FullName` to get the full path to the file.

Comment: That seems to have gotten me most of the way there. Just a couple of tweaks now. Thank you.

Comment: Default property is more of VB thing.  FileInfo.Name is not decorated with any such attribute.  PowerShell uses more of an algorithm that IIRC uses ToString() as the backstop. But I have run into this issue before where .FullName fixes the problem.  OTOH from a quick experiment, Move-Item seems to work fine with FileInfo objects that have a Name sans path info - try it.  You can see the result it reaches with a call to `[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo($fileInfo, [string])`.  I was somewhat surprised to see this work, but it does on V3 - at least for me.  :-)

Comment: @KeithHill When I tested this, `Move-Item $file ...` complained that the filename couldn't be found in the current working directory. `$file.ToString()` also produced just the filename without the path. It would seem that `Get-ChildItem` uses `GetFiles()` to enumerate the files, which [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.tostring.aspx) doesn't construct the `FileInfo` objects with the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$oldFiles = Get-ChildItem $oldPath -Recurse -Exclude "dir 2" | Where-Object { $_.lastwritetime -le $oldDate}`

Comment: That won't work, because **-Exclude** doesn't affect recursive listings. `-Exclude "dir 2"` will prevent **dir 2** itself from being included, but not its contents. So, for example, if `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude "dir 2" | Remove-Item` is invoked when **root** is the working directory, **dir 2** itself will not be removed, but all its contents will be removed, including subdirectories and their contents.